# property/field Attribute in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

We use `Attribute` in C# like:

`[Required]
string email;`

how we can achieve this in **JavaScript**

I used the following but this doesn't sends back

```js
var c=function(){
    Object.defineProperties(this,{
        a:{
            writable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            required:true
        }
    });
}
var c1=new c();
var d=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(c1, 'a');
console.log(JSON.stringify(d))
for(var k in d)
    console.log(k+' = '+d[k]);
```

**`required` is missing**

Comment: JavaScript is not C#. You cannot define your own attributes.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript `required` is not a property descriptor.

Comment: @messerbill, in that code "required" is not a property descriptor, it is a property named "required". See this doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty ) this behaviour can be explained. Open the link and read the `Description`.

There are several parameters which can be defined and `required` is not one of them. This is why it will not be applied to your Object. If you want to achieve this you have to do somethink like this:

```js
var c=function(){
    Object.defineProperties(this,{
        a:{
            writable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });
}
var c1=new c();
var d=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(c1, 'a');
d.required = true; // THIS LINE
console.log(JSON.stringify(d))
for(var k in d)
    console.log(k+' = '+d[k]);
```

Comment: thanks @messerbill, but your change will not work as I need to give `required` as attribute when define a property and later to get back that which properties are required

Comment: have you read the docs? This is not possible using `defineProperties()`